# Is type erasure of getters and their return types (introspection) possible without heap allocations?

Tags: c++, introspection, type-erasure

I am trying to write some form of type erased introspection for member getters and haven't been able to do it without heap allocations.

Is there a way to do this while eliminating "new" in the lambda?

Can I carry the return value across erasure into the caller's memory spot with some sort of copy elision, reference or move trick despite the erasure in between it?

[  Caller memory]  <-  void* (?) <-  GetThing()

Here is an example:

https://godbolt.org/z/r8er1aWfx

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>



struct CopyTest
{
    CopyTest()
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    CopyTest(const CopyTest& rhs)
    {
        x = rhs.x + 1;
    }
    int x = 0;
};

struct Object
{
    CopyTest getValue()
    {
        return val;
    }

    CopyTest val;
};

struct AnotherObject
{
    CopyTest getValue()
    {
        return val;
    }

    CopyTest val;
};


struct TypeErasureBase
{
    uint64_t m_typeInfoPtr;  // Let's just pretend it's a typeID for this example
    void* m_typeData;
};


template<
    typename ReturnType,
    typename ClassType
>
static std::function<TypeErasureBase(void*)> registerGetMethod(ReturnType(ClassType::* getMethod)(void))
{
    return [=](void* erasedObject) -> TypeErasureBase
    {
        const uint64_t typeID = 1;
        void* typeErasedData = new std::remove_reference_t<ReturnType>((reinterpret_cast<ClassType*>(erasedObject)->*getMethod)());

        return {
            typeID,
            typeErasedData
        };
    };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::function someErasureFunction = registerGetMethod(&Object::getValue);
    const std::function someOtherErasureFunction = registerGetMethod(&AnotherObject::getValue);


    Object valTest;
    AnotherObject anotherTest;

    void* valTestPtr = &valTest;
    void* anotherTestPtr = &anotherTest;

    //...
    /// Somewhere else in codebase where Object and AnotherObject aren't directly know
    //...

    const int val = static_cast<CopyTest*>(someErasureFunction(valTestPtr).m_typeData)->x;
    const int val2 = static_cast<CopyTest*>(someOtherErasureFunction(anotherTestPtr).m_typeData)->x;

    std::cout << "Copies: " << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Copies: " << val2 << std::endl;

}
```

I've tried other goofy things like void& or void&& but as I understand it now that is nonsense and doesn't mean anything.

Comment: That's rather unlikely.

Comment: How come `registerGetMethod` doesn't actually use its `getMethod` parameter?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. `someOtherErasureFunction(anotherTestPtr)` effectively casts `AnotherObject*` to `Object*`, then calls a method on an invalid pointer thus obtained.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you are right I messed up when I was de-simplifying it a few steps back up closer to what we use internally and missed that part.   I'll edit it to correct that.

Comment: A common trick to avoid allocation is the small object optimization. You reserve a small buffer within `TypeErasureBase` object. Then the lambda may construct the actual data into that buffer via placement new if it's small enough, and allocate on the heap otherwise. However, this only works for trivially copyable objects (basically, those you can `memcpy` around); it would technically be illegal for `CopyTest` which is not trivially copyable.

Comment: `TypeErasureBase` looks like reinvention of `std::any`, so you could just use that. `std::any` very likely uses heap allocation internally, but perhaps employs small object optimization.

Comment: You can't. The caller has to statically know the size of the return value _before_ calling a function. Returning arbitrary types means that's impossible.